# Split labels of values on xaxis in a SAS graph into two lines

Tags: sas

I have the below graph created by `Proc sgplot`. Since the labels of values on the xaxis is too long, I want to put them in two lines. For example, instead of "T2 to T3 (Pre-pandemic to initial pandemic)", I'd like to have
line 1:           T2 to T3
line 2: (Pre-pandemic to initial pandemic)" .
I have created these labels using `proc format`. Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the options `FITPOLICY` and `SPLITCHAR` for the `XAXIS` statement.

For you, this would be

```
xaxis ... fitpolicy=split splitchar="(";
```

For further details, consult the [documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/grstatproc/p07m2vpyq75fgan14m6g5pphnwlr.htm#n1bkk2fwzh9l7in1que4qmkricsxa).

Comment: Many thanks, it did work! I used fitpolicy=splitalways to split all three labels.